# Boxes with folded corner and box shadow over an unpredictable background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

The boxes have shadows and the background of the corners must be transparent because they are over an image (unpredictable background).

After searching Google, I found solutions using pseudo selectors `:before` and `:after` as well as solutions using extra markup, but all of them use a fixed colour background. These were my results:

[image]

I'm trying to use box-shadows and only a small image for the corner, instead of a large complete background.

How I can do this?

Comment: Any reason my answer wasn't marked as correct, when it at least works in one browser, and looks the same as the answer you marked as correct in other browsers?

Comment: Your answer is aceptable, but I need at least a minimun compatibility with IE. I will vote up your answer!

Comment: Because I'm not the author of it, I'm not sending it as an answer, but it's fully working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Flocke/9btv5/0/
There are folded corner that made on background image using css3 gradients. Worth to look, I found only it works best with all my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use both the pseudo-elements, one for the upper box, the other for the white triangle:

```css
h1 {
    background: #F0B032;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #362708;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}
​h1:before {
    background: #F0B032;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #362708;
    width: 15px;
    height: 16px;
    top: 0;
}
h1:after {
    border: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #fff;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

​Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kjp6v/

---

This does not add a shadow under the fold, but looks realistic enough.

Comment: You can create that little image yourself and add it as a background: http://jsfiddle.net/Kjp6v/1/ (not the right image, but you get the point)

Comment: Your answer is right, but I need this for large content (multiline), not h1 tag . [http://jsfiddle.net/QACBa/](http://jsfiddle.net/QACBa/)

Comment: @smoreno - Then remove the height, and set `bottom` to `14px`: http://jsfiddle.net/Kjp6v/2/