# Slanted div corner over background image

Tags: css, background-image, pseudo-element

I am trying to create a transparent border in the upper left of a div that overlays a background image. I found this post: [Boxes with folded corner and box shadow over an unpredictable background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240350/boxes-with-folded-corner-and-box-shadow-over-an-unpredictable-background) which is close to what I am trying to achieve, except I couldn't get the accepted answer to work.

Attached is a screen shot of what I have so far. You will notice the slightly grayed out triangle in the upper left. That area should be transparent so you can see the background image behind it.

[image]

Here is my current CSS that has gotten me to where I am now:

```
.interior-banner .subnav {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,51);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,51,.8);
    border: 0;
    height: 240px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 30px 20px 20px; 
    -moz-background-clip: padding; 
    -webkit-background-clip: padding;  
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
.interior-banner .subnav:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    border-top: 20px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    border-right: 40px solid transparent;
}
```

How can I get the specified corner to be transparent over the background image rather than the div?

Comment: JSfiddle please, but you can't make an overlay that will affect the opacity of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is a gradient background

for instance:

```
.interior-banner .subnav {
    background: linear-gradient(145deg, rgba(0,0,151, 0.5) 50px, rgb(0,0,151) 50px);
    border: 0;
    height: 240px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding: 30px 20px 20px; 
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bY38/2/)